# Backbone structure

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone, but have watched several tutorial screencasts on it, both with and without requirejs.

My question involves the setup structure (both file structure if using require, and/or variable/object structure).

Most of the tutorials I have watched, seem to prefer a App.Models, App.Collections, and App.Views approach, and each item inside has the name of the module: ie,

```
App.Models.todo = Backbone.Model.extend({...});
App.Collections.todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({...});
App.Views.todo = Backbone.View.extend({...});
```

After a little research, trying to find someone that uses the same style as I would like to use, I finally found: [File structure for a web app using requirejs and backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034706/file-structure-for-a-web-app-using-requirejs-and-backbone). They seem to prefer more of a App.[Module Name] method: ie,

```
App.Todo.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({...});
App.Todo.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({...});
App.Todo.Views = Backbone.View.extend({...});
```

I personally prefer the App.[Module Name] structure over having my modules split up, but would like to know the benefits, if any, of having the different structures.

Which structure do you use, and how has it helped you over a different structure you may have seen or used in the past?

Comment: It is mostly a matter of personal preference. I don't think you're going to get more than a bunch of opinions.

Comment: It's a question of workflow. Either you root by component type (`App.Models.*`) (i.e. one developer works primarily on views, other on models), or you optimize for context (`App.Accounts.Model`) to keep things (business)-logically grouped. But like @muistooshort said, this question cannot be objectively answered, and as such not really suitable for the StackOverflow format.

Comment: I agree that most of the answers will be opinions. I was just trying to see if there was any actual benefits to one over the other, if there was some 'best practice' that I hadn't seen, or if it is 100% opinion ("whatever you're comfortable with").

Comment: @PaulWitschger, without getting down to theoretical cultural relativism, I would say it's just opinion. Obviously there are better and worse ways. I wouldn't, for example, recommend naming all your files by GUIDs, but between the two ways you propose, it's up to you. I do `App.{Module}.*`, FWIW.

Comment: Here is a resource that can be used as a starting point: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach described in this blog:
http://weblog.bocoup.com/organizing-your-backbone-js-application-with-modules/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using requireJS you don't need/want to attach the models/views to a global namespace object attached to the window (no App.Views, App.Models). One of the nice things about using requireJS or a different AMD module loader is that you can avoid globals.

You can define a model like this:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], 
    function(_, Backbone) {
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    return MyModel;
});
```

Then you define a view:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'tpl!templates/someTemplate.html'],
  function(_, Backbone, template) {
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({});

  return MyView;
});
```

Now you have a model and a view with no globals. Then if some other module needs to create one of these (maybe your App module), you add it to the `define()` array and you have it.

Comment: if you read the second paragraph of my question, I also refer to file structure if using require (not just namespacing). By the location of the template in your example, I would assume you use models/, views/, collections/, and templates/ ? Not module/model, module/collection, etc? If so, what was the reason you went this route? What is the benefit vs the module/ route?

Comment: It is very subjective like others said, and I don't have a strong opinion on that part :) The possible problem with module/model and module/view is that you might someday decide to use a particular model from one 'module' with another 'module.'  But, I think there is a confusion with the term 'module' here meaning 2 things. With requireJS, the 'module' is whatever you define and return, usually a constructor for an object (model/view/etc.) like in the code in my post. There is another concept of 'module' being a collection of these things (model + view + ...).